# What System Table Contains All the Control Properties of a Form in MS Access?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I need to get the control properties right from the system table, if there's a way. on the MSysNavPaneObjectIDs system table, I can get my form name and its ID but, there's not any property of the controls of this form. how can I get it from a system table?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There is no system table to view the form's control properties.  You can only view those using VBA.  For example:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim formName As String
    Dim frm As Form
    Dim ctrl As Control
    Dim prop As Property

    formName = "frmMain"
    Set frm = Forms(formName)
    For Each ctrl In frm.Controls
        Debug.Print ctrl.Name
        For Each prop In ctrl.Properties
            Debug.Print vbTab & prop.Name
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: hello mdialogo, I must avoid using this loop because I need to get the controls properties before opening the form. can I save the control object in a table?

Comment: @MyThorRJ you can save the controls and property names in a table using the CurrentDb.Execute command (not the object itself).  For example, you can replace the second Debug.Print above with CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO FormControls (ControlName, PropertyName) VALUES (ctrl.Name, prop.Name)"

Comment: the problem of saving the control name is when I need to make changes. I'd have to change in the table, as well.